# In Github, how can i put the index.html to open automatically in my hosted website

Tags: html, github, github-pages

when i put: 
https://vitorfigm.github.io/ 
it gives me: 
"There isn't a GitHub Pages site here". 
but with: https://vitorfigm.github.io/My-Web-site-template/index.html  
it opens normally, how can i put this index.html to open automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your site at the address https://vitorfigm.github.io/, you will have to rename your repo to the format **`<username>`.github.io**. In your case, it would be **vitorfigm.github.io**.

That's the only way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't.
You could however get a cheap Domain and link it to your GitHub Page. So you would access https://vitorfigm.github.io/My-Web-site-template/index.html with for example vitorfigm.com.